# \xdef with arguments in \newcommand?

Tags: macros, graphics

Considering this `newcommand` (it works fine)

```
\newcommand\createCMDSH[4]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #3#2\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #3#2\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\vcenteredhbox{\noexpand\includegraphics[height=\noexpand\taille,trim=0 0 1 -1]{BD_CATIA/#4/#1.png}}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

I can obtain a command with a name specified by `#3#2` for displaying a picture.

The idea is to change the `xdef` command for building a new `#3#2` command with one argument. How can I do this? Is `xdef` the right command?

**Explanation (`#3#2`=`cmdperso`):**

- old version `\cmdperso{}`
- new version `\cmdperso{0.5}` (50% of the `\textwidth`)

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
\newcommand\createCMDM[4]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #3#2\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #3#2\endcsname[1][]{%
      \noexpand\includegraphics[width=\noexpand##1\textwidth]{BD_CATIA/#4/#1.png}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
\newcommand\createCMDM[4]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #3#2\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #3#2\endcsname##1{%
      \noexpand\includegraphics[width=##1\noexpand\hsize]{BD_CATIA/#4/#1.png}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Comment: Since you're expanding nothing in the replacement text for `\xdef`, what are you using it for?

Comment: In fact I call `\createCMDM` using: `\createCMDM{...}{\txtA}{\txtB}{...}` and `\txtA` and `\txtB` contain `perso` and `cmd`. But maybe I misunderstand the expand process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You combine the `\newcommand` syntax of parameter declarations with `\xdef` primitive. But primitive commands have normal and elegant syntax without square brackets.

```
\def\createCMDM#1#2#3#4{% I don't understand why #3 is merged with #2
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #3#2\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #3#2\endcsname##1{%
      \includegraphics[width=##1\hsize]{BD_CATIA/#4/#1.png}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

If you are using `\cmdperso{}` for full `\hsize` and `\cmdperso{0.5}` for half `\hsize`, then you don't need to implement the optional parameter.

Edit: I replace `\xdef` to `\gdef` and remove one `\noexpand`. The `\xdef` is not needed here.

Comment: Actually, the OP needs `\xdef`, as explained in the last comment to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an emulation of what `\newcommand` with two optional argument does, but I think it's better using `xparse` and `expl3` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createCMDSH}{mmmm}
 {
  \guuk_create_cmdsh:cxx { #3#2 } { #1 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \guuk_create_cmdsh:Nnn
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}
   {
    \vcenteredhbox{
     \includegraphics[height=\taille,trim=0~0~1~-1]{BD_CATIA/#3/#2.png}
    }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \guuk_create_cmdsh:Nnn { cxx }

\NewDocumentCommand{\createCMDM}{mmmm}
 {
  \guuk_create_cmdm:cxx { #3#2 } { #1 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \guuk_create_cmdm:Nnn
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{O{}}
   {
    \vcenteredhbox{
     \includegraphics[width=##1\textwidth]{BD_CATIA/#3/#2.png}
    }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \guuk_create_cmdm:Nnn { cxx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\txtA}{TEXTA}
\newcommand{\txtB}{TEXTB}
\createCMDSH{\txtA}{\txtB}{X}{Y} % this will create \XTEXTB

\createCMDM{\txtA}{\txtB}{ZZZ}{WWW} % this will create `\ZZZTEXTB`
```

The command `\ZZZTEXTB` will have an optional argument, so `\ZZZTEXTB` would print the image `\textwidth` wide, while `\ZZZTEXTB[0.5]` will print it half of the textwidth.

Comment: Thanks but Can I use the same syntax as I used in my first command? Just by adding some argument?

Comment: @Guuk If you want a regular (braced) argument, just add `##1` after `\endcsname`, instead of `[1][]`. With the `xparse/expl3` approach it's easier to manage expansions.